# How do I disable filesystem checking on boot in 20.04?

Tags: grub2, surface, 20.04

Whenever I boot Ubuntu 20.04 on my computer, I get a message saying "Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress." is there any way to stop auto disk checking?

This happens with and without the Surface Linux kernel.  If you want more info (such as my GRUB config) I'll answer it in the comments.

This did not happen when I used 18.04.

Comment: You should see that message only when booting live/install media, have you installed it?

Comment: If you're helping to test the development release (*focal fossa* isn't 20.04 until release time), then you can also use #ubuntu-quality via IRC or telegram, however general support should still go to #ubuntu+1 sites until *focal fossa* has been released and reached stable 20.04).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  NOTE: As you installed it I'd recommend using a quality/+1 site and/or filing a bug

Comment: @guiverc yes I have installed it.  I forgot that this is a development release and my question will be off-topic for two more days.

Comment: 20.04 was off-topic yesterday, today it is on-topic, what joy is there in closing a question on a technicality? @TwentyCharMax I get the disk check every time I boot a 20.04 Live/Persistent drive. If I am slow hitting ctl-c it tales a few minutes to close. This is very irritating. Good subject for a Bug Report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this works for you, in brief:

```
tune2fs -c 0 /dev/yourdevicehere
```

Note: `yourdevicehere` is where your `/` (root) is mounted. To check its location, run the following command:

```
df -h
```

Source: [How to force file system check (fsck) after system reboot on Linux](https://support.hostway.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000920290-How-to-force-file-system-check-fsck-after-system-reboot-on-Linux)

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try this soon and update on how it goes.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

### Removing Disk Check From 20.04 Boot

The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check when booting Ubuntu 20.04.

The line `Checking disks: 0% complete` may still come up but fsck will not be run, nor will boot time be increased.

Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the `linux line` in grub.cfg just before `quiet splash`

It is recommended to add the command to grub.cfg by editing /etc/default/grub thus: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip quiet splash"` and then run `sudo update-grub`.

I have had this problem with a Live USB but not with an installed system.

Comment: Reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1875548

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same problem in the last releases of Ubuntu. Right now, I have Ubuntu 21.10 installed and it still has it. Trying the solution from @wazeredo46 did not work for me. But I managed to find some sort of solution. I have dual boot with Windows 10, and apparently Ubuntu does not like that. The partition it is always checking at boot is the ESP one. To fix that, I changed its 'pass' argument in fstab from 1 to 0. I would recommend keeping the other partitions with their original pass values, as it will make it possible for errors to be detected.