# How to permanently disable filesystem check on boot Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

So first of all its no a duplicate question, because i tried all options of the same questions and none of it worked.

I tried this one (it didnt work): [How do I disable filesystem checking on boot in 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229050/how-do-i-disable-filesystem-checking-on-boot-in-20-04)

I tried to edit `/etc/fstab` as **super user** and change `dump` and `pass` to `0` on my `root` partition, didn't work as well.

I just did a fresh installation of ubuntu on my SSD and i'm trying to disable it, so i can say all my configs are default.

Also i'm using dual-boot with Windows 10 on the same disk, i don't know if this has someting to do, but may be good let you know.

The only thing that worked (but not permanently) was append `fastboot` in Ubuntu option when i'm on GRUB screen, after pression `e` with Ubuntu selected.

Comment: To get sufficiently different answers, you must ask a sufficiently different question. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): You are asking about your preferred solution (disable fsck) instead of asking why your filesystem needs to be repaired upon every boot.

Comment: Here is another method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250119/how-to-skip-filesystem-checks-during-boot

Comment: @C.S.Cameron **Not a good idea. You WANT fsck to run if it finds file system problems.** Better to find/fix the reason for constant file system repairs.

Comment: @heynnema: Many people have complained about file system check running after every boot of 20.04 and never actually finding a filesystem error. After a while it gets very old. https://askubuntu.com/search?q=20.04+filesystem+check. This happens every boot in Live systems and every time in some installed systems. It is not much use if it doesn't help you fix things. Nobody has come back to me and said that it broke their computer. I have not heard of it happening in 18.04 or previous.

Comment: My Bug Report can be found here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1875548

Comment: @C.S.Cameron You have more experience than myself when working with a 20.04 system. I'd be interested to see, in an unmodified grub, how a manual fsck when booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB runs. External things can cause file system corruption, that forces a fsck... like having a Windows driver installed that allows reading/writing to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions... or a failing HDD/SSD. `tune2fs` also has some settings that need to be checked. Also, Ubuntu Live DVD/USB always runs a file system check ON ITSELF to confirm a good DVD/USB build, before somebody does a bad install.

Comment: @heynnema: From what I can see, the automatic filesystem check that was present in Ubuntu 20.04 Live has been removed in Ubuntu 21.04. This would mean that in 20.04 it was either due to a bug or to a bad decision. Maybe you want to reconsider your highlighted statement above.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Please tell/show me how you determined that automatic fsck has been removed from 21.04. /etc/fstab shows no indication of this. I'm not aware of any tune2fs values that have changed. The Ubuntu Live 21.04 still does auto check at boot time, if I'm not mistaken... I could be wrong about that...

Comment: @heynnema: I used Rufus and Etcher to make Live USB's. I booted the USB's with and without `quiet splash` neither of them ran Filesystem check. I have never been able to get an automatic filesystem check with and installed system.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron We were originally talking about disabling fsck on normal runtime systems, not Live DVD/USB. That's what I was talking about with my comment not to disable it.

Comment: @heynnema: If you search AU for '20.04 filesystem check' you will see 48 complaints mostly about automatic filesystem check. many are about installed systems. If you search AU for '21.04 filesystem check' you will see 5 posts, none of which are complaints, about either Live systems or installed systems faulty checks. Do you see a solution to any problems when the filesystem check shows no errors? If it shows no errors it is not worth running, (I think).

Comment: @C.S.Cameron That goes back to another comment that I made... about running a manual `fsck` when booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Many times it'll find errors that the automatic, repeating, file system check can't. Many users may not have the time/knowledge/tenacity to want to find out WHY something is happening... they just complain about the apparent reoccurring visual message. Until I'm shown/told that the user has made efforts to try and fix a broken file system, my comment stands... don't disable automatic checks on installed systems.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I put together a quick `fsck` answer for the OP. Let's see if they take the time to test it...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema i tried `fsck` command using a live DVD it didnt work, i even reinstalled ubuntu, i'm almost sure it was something to do with Windows dual boot, i had to erase everything from my SSD and reinstall Windows than Ubuntu so everything was installed correctly and i'm not getting the filesystem check on boot anymore. But when using HD i had this message for 1 year i thought it was normal, i recommend disable this thing following my answer if you had this message on boot all the time, its the only way, because there is no error no filesystem, you can check it how many times you want.

Answer (score 1):

Let's manually check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Note**: If `fsck` finds/repairs problems, remove **fastboot** from your /etc/default/grub, and `sudo update-grub`.

**Note**: You can also start `gparted` and see if it finds any problem with the partition table, or errors when the partition is "Checked" (a choice from the menu).

**Note**: You can also `sudo fdisk -l` to see if it finds any partition errors.

**Note**: You can also use the `Disks` **SMART Data & Tests** window to determine if there's any pending disk failure. Ignore any "Your disk is OK" messages.

**Note**: If you dual-boot with Windows, and you have a Windows driver installed that allows you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions, remove this driver asap, as it WILL corrupt Linux partitions.

Comment: It didnt work, tried it, i had this message for 1 year and thought it was normal for Ubuntu, i had to reinstall everything on my SSD Windows and Ubuntu to make it stop. It's just a bug, as i said in another comment, you can try to check your disk how many times you want, it never finds any error, just follow my answer and enjoy a faster boot if you are using a HD

Comment: @JoãoHamerski Did you also do my **Notes** from my answer? `gparted`, `fdisk`, Windows ext2/3/4 driver? Show me a screenshot of the SMART data.

Answer (score -1):

**[SOLVED]**

I found a way to persist the `fastboot` command, that disables filesystem check.

Following this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

You can persist `fastboot` option on boot

- Open grub options file `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- Find for `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT"`
- Probably it will be something like that `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` as default
- Append  `fastboot` inside the double quotes
- It should be like this `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash fastboot"`
- Run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes

Comment: Since fsck will only be called if something is broken in your filesystem, your solution fixes the symptom, not the cause. And yes: this the the standard way of adding flags during boot. So why is a fsck necessary in the first place ? If you don't run it, your filesystem might get corrupted beyond repair.

Comment: No, there is nothing broken, its a fresh installation of ubuntu, my old installation always checked filesystem on boot too.

Comment: Mine doesn't without the flag - maybe Windows is the culprit - that i don't use

Comment: If there is something broken so fsck isnt doing its job, since it always check the filesystem, right? If i understood fsck should fix what is broken, but seems it is checking everytime on boot and doing nothing, so...

Comment: Likely what is broken is the way the machine is being shut down from linux.  If it isn't shut down correctly, it needs a fsck on next boot or you risk major corruption or boot failures.

Comment: **Not a good idea. You WANT fsck to run if it finds file system problems**. Better to find/fix the reason for constant file system repairs.