# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS start-up message/check which delays boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd, bootloader

I am having Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS dual boot system. Windows 11 on regular SSD while Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on PCIE NVME SSD.
It's Dell XPS 8930 Desktop(2018) where I have made a lot of upgrades and additions.
As part of the latest upgrade, I upgraded 512GB PCIE NVME SSD(version 1) to 4 TB PCIE NVME SSD(ver 4.0). I used [AOMEI cloning software for this](https://www.aomeitech.com/pa/professional.html) . In the process of upgrading PCIE NVME SSD, I removed the swap partition as it was not being used any more.
Disk cloning was successful. After that I just swapped the old PCIE NVME SSD with new PCIE NVME SSD in the desktop.

Dual boot - windows and Linux all booted properly. But the only issue is this check that is there. In the past also I had this check but it was a smaller PCIE NVME SSD but now it is for larger PCIE NVME SSD.

[image]
Message is as follows:
SGX Launch Control is locked. Support SGX virtualization only. I believe this might be due to the fact that I have enabled virtualization in the BIOS. This message is quick.
But after that it's sort of check disk kind of process. Mine PCIE NVME SSD(on which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is installed is 4TB) so this check disk kind of check is really slowing down the boot process.
How I can disable this checkdisk kind of process.

/etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=e6311f73-982f-4037-95ec-23a60032ff67 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=8DED-981F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
```

cat /proc/cmdline

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-43-generic root=UUID=e6311f73-982f-4037-95ec-23a60032ff67 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

Tried this [approach](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250119/how-to-skip-filesystem-checks-during-boot) also but no success.
Tried this [approach](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229050/how-do-i-disable-filesystem-checking-on-boot-in-20-04) also but no success.
Here is the [video of this issue](https://youtu.be/Sl7ADpqvojI)

I think this could be the [potential issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590518/boot-blocks-with-gave-up-waiting-for-suspend-resume-device)

Comment: Whats the entry in `/etc/fstab` for this partition? `fsck` is configured in `/etc/fstab`, see `man fstab`. Does the fsck occur on every boot or only by switching from Windows to Linux?

Comment: # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=e6311f73-982f-4037-95ec-23a60032ff67 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=8DED-981F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation

Comment: Is it anything to do with this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231734/disable-ubuntu-20-04-disk-checkup-every-boot

Comment: Please add the information in formatted way to the question, not to the comment.

Comment: fsck of root filesystem is handled by `systemd-fsck-root.service` (see `man systemd-fsck-root.service`). Please add the output of `cat /proc/cmdline` to the question (formatted and readable!).

Comment: everything added in main question with formatting.

Comment: There are now two solutions: First the easy one, just disable the fsck. This can be done by adding `fsck.mode=skip` as kernel option or change the number "1" to "0" in `/etc/fstab`. (see `man systemd-fsck-root.service` and `man fstab`). The second one is difficult, because you have to find the reason for the fsck run. Usually this is a "guess" and "test" procedure.

Comment: @Marco-made that change but no impact. Still after GRUB-choosing Ubuntu the same check happens which delays the boot by almost 25 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SGX is a system that attempts to provide virtual machines that are secure *against the owner of the physical host*. If this is your personal system, you probably won't need it, and the technology seems to be flawed anyway: see https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/08/architectural-bug-in-some-intel-cpus-is-more-bad-news-for-sgx-users/

When the message `/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean [...]` appears, that means the filesystem check is **done**.

If you removed a swap partition, you should check the following three configuration files for a reference to it, and update or comment it out as necessary:

- `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`
- `/etc/uswsusp.conf`
- `/etc/suspend.conf`

After making changes, you should run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to make sure the changes take effect also in the earliest part of the boot process.

Depending on your system configuration, some of the files listed above may or may not exist. That's fine: you are just looking for reference to the removed swap partition in those configuration files that *do* exist.

Comment: I don't have any of these 3 references

Comment: If you did not update your initramfs after removing the swap partition from `/etc/fstab`, then just running `sudo update-initramfs -u` helps by updating the copy of fstab within the initramfs, so the early boot scripts will no longer see a reference to a swap partition and so will no longer attempt to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I was getting this message which was causing delayed boot was due to the reason that ***while upgrading my ubuntu PCI NVME SSD, I also removed the swap partition.***
**System was expecting SWAP partition on this upgraded drive but not finding and thus there was delay in the booting process.**

Followed this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590518/boot-blocks-with-gave-up-waiting-for-suspend-resume-device)
and ran `update-initramfs -u`
to get this issue fixed for ever.